# SELECT query not retrieving up to date data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently I have a dropdown menu and a text area. By selecting a number from the dropdown you get the corresponding data loaded into the text area from my sql database. There is also a button to save/edit the text, this works and updates the database successfully. However what does not work is when new text is entered into the text area, its saved, selecting another number from drop down and then going back to the previous one the new text does not appear, the old text does, even though the database has been updated.

Previously when I submitted the form the page reloaded which meant everything worked fine, however since then I needed to stop this reloading which I did, now the dropdown isn't retrieving the up to date data from the database?

dropdown onchange function (course.php)

```
function selectedItem(selection){




  if(selection=="page1"){

   document.getElementById("commentid").value = "<?php query2('page1',$_SESSION['courseID'], $_SESSION['userID']) ?>";

  }

  if(selection=="page2"){

    document.getElementById("commentid").value = "<?php query2('page2',$_SESSION['courseID'], $_SESSION['userID']) ?>";
  }

  if(selection=="page3"){

    document.getElementById("commentid").value = "<?php query2('page3',$_SESSION['courseID'], $_SESSION['userID']) ?>";
  }

  if(selection=="page4"){

    document.getElementById("commentid").value = "<?php query2('page4',$_SESSION['courseID'], $_SESSION['userID']) ?>";
  }

  if(selection=="page5"){

    document.getElementById("commentid").value = "<?php query2('page5',$_SESSION['courseID'], $_SESSION['userID']) ?>";
  }


}
```

'commentid' being the id of the text area

query2 code (func.inc.php)

```
function query2($page,$courseID,$userID){//POPULATE COMMENT BOX FROM THE CORRECT PAGE, COURSE ID AND USER ID
        $myData = mysql_query("SELECT {$page} FROM comments WHERE user_id='{$userID}' AND course_id='{$courseID}'");
        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
            echo $record[$page] ;   
        }


    }
```

When reloading the page the latest comment will now be visible for each dropdown option. It would seem the SELECT query is not retrieving the latest data from the database?

Comment: What is your problem? Php is executed when the page is loaded (server side), if you want something dynamic for client use ajax.

Comment: Since you stopped the page from reloading, it is normal that the text does not update... You would need to grab the page again or at least the part that interests you.

Answer (score 0):

The new text isn't displayed because it isn't in the browser.

What you're doing is this:

1) Load **course.php** from the server. It creates the function `selectedItem(selection)` and outputs it to the browser. Inside the browser, the function now looks like this:

```
if(selection=="page1"){
   document.getElementById("commentid").value = "Text A";
  }

if(selection=="page2"){
   document.getElementById("commentid").value = "Text B";
  }
```

etc....

2) You post 'Text CCCC' for `page1`. This post is picked up by the server and put into the database. The browser however still has the old javascript and has no way of knowing there is a new text. Only if you somehow change the  javascript, you get to see the new text.

There are a few options to do this:

Refresh the page, like you did before. The function `selectedItem` will be created again an now contains the new `Text CCCC` from the database. This is the simplest solution.

If you don't want to refresh the page, you can replace the content of the javascript in the browser. To do so, you could do this:

In **course.php**

```
var text=new Array(
   'page1'=>"<?php query2('page1',$_SESSION['courseID'], $_SESSION['userID']) ?>",
   'page2'=>"<?php query2('page2',$_SESSION['courseID'], $_SESSION['userID']) ?>",
   'page3'=>"<?php query2('page3',$_SESSION['courseID'], $_SESSION['userID']) ?>"
      );
var selected_page='page1';

function selectedItem(selection){
   selected_page=selection;
   document.getElementById("commentid").value = text[selection];
}
```

Now the browser has an javascript array called 'text', containing the text of the different pages:

```
Text=['page1'=>'Text A','page2'=>'Text B','page3'=>'Text C']
```

Everytime you run your function `selectedItem` it puts the value of the selected text variable inside `commentid`. It also updates the variable `selected_page`, so you can keep track on what variable is displayed.

When you post your form, you only have to change the content of the corresponding variable. This could be done like:

In your form add this:

```
<form onsubmit="change_text()">
```

And add a little javascript function

```
function change_text(){
   //replace the corresponding variable with the new text
   text[selected_page]=document.getElementById('mytextarea').value;

   return true; // (to submit the form)
}
```

This will overwrite the value of `text[selected_page]` with the text in the textarea. Now javascript 'knows' that there is new text an can display it. So if you changed page1 to 'Text DDDDD', the array now contains

```
Text=['page1'=>'Text DDDDD','page2'=>'Text B','page3'=>'Text C']
```

**Note** This is a (very) simplified example. It is for one not checking if the post is correctly handled by the server. So you could still end up with different texts in the browser and the database. I suggest you look into ajax (possibly jquery ajax) to do it properly.